# Using Associations in Sequelize.js to Achieve Database Normalization

Tags: node.js, sqlite, associations, sequelize.js

Hi I am using **sequelize** as the **ORM** for my project implemented in **NodeJs**. In a table i have a huge number of columns. So I want to split the columns into 3 tables. So basically i want to split a Model into 3 different Models and sync to get the model into 3 different tables in the DB(sqlite in my case) and i want to fetch it as a single object (all the columns of the 3 tables). Is this possible? I can use inheritance, but i did not find much about it in "sequelize". Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are attempting to "normalize" your database:

> Database normalization is the process of organizing the fields and
>   tables of a relational database to minimize redundancy and dependency. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Once you've split the single table as you've suggested, you will want to utilize [Sequelize's associations](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#associations-one-to-one) to retrieve information from the "associated" tables.

If you require more detailed help, you will have to add detail to your question in the form of what your database models currently look like, and possibly what information you want to split off into new models.